# Install multiple SAP Crystal Reports versions?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2022

I have multiple Windows applications, some are built on Visual Studio version 13 and others are built on version 22. Now I cannot use these applications simultaneously because these apps require different SAP Crystal Reports versions.

How to install in several versions of Crystal Reports at once?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue so i prepared a package with files from SP25 (last version compatible with 3500 release number) from the following folders:

- managed
- win32_x86
- win64_x64

before installing the latest release, which uninstall any old version.
Then registered the following libraries from win32_x86/dotnet into the GAC using gacutil.exe:

```
CRVsPackageLib.dll
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Design.dll
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.TemplateEngine.dll
CrystalDecisions.Data.AdoDotNetInterop.dll
CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Viewing.ReportSource.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonControls.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonObjectModel.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CubeDefModel.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ObjectFactory.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Prompting.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll
CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll
CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.dll
CrystalDecisions.Web.dll
CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.dll
SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.dll
SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.ViewerShared.dll
```

I prepared this package several years ago so i cannot recall the reason i took those 3 folders. But it works.
Recently log4net.dll, Version=1.2.10.0 has been removed from GAC so i had to re-add manually to let this work again